# Magneto 2 edit configurable products sku and product undefined

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, product-attribute, undefined-variable

New product creating configurable product

**step 1:** Select Attributes - selected color then,

**Step 2:** Attribute Values - selected 2 colors then.

**Step 3:** Selected Skip image uploading at this time

**Step 4:** Summary - SKUis undefined-attribute value (undefined-grey) after generating product,
grid format below can check product name is undefined-#5 Vanilla Beige also sku

[image]

Answer (score 0):

my be you not add a simple preselect value

add  simple preselect value

http://prntscr.com/tf4vxt

Ex. abcd

than after create new child product